# Gradient at a critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Why should the gradient be $0$ at a critical point? I'm not sure the reason other then we set the gradient of a function to zero to find the critical points.

Comment: How have you defined "critical point"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The critical point of $f(x,y)$ is defined where $f_x = 0 = f_y$,and the gradient of $f$ is defined $\nabla f = (f_x,f_y)$. Thus it would be zero at critical point. It should be a comment but I tried capitalize on it...

Comment: This does answer the question. The only thing I would change is to make the result more general. That is, for a function $f$ defined on $X\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ (for any $n\in\Bbb N$), $v\in\ X$ is defined to be critical when $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(v)=0~~\forall i\iff\nabla f=0 $$